# XamarinForms/ C# Resx.File SwitchCase

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating a mobile app in Xamarin.Forms. I am using resx file for my strings, but i got to a case where i need to use the switch case but switch wont allow me to use strings from my resx file as constant must be used. I want my app to have two languages maybe more in the future and the user should be able to switch between them. I found some posts that i should use IF instead but the switch is more suitable. Do you have any experience in this?

Once i want to replace Case with my Label it wont allow me because it needs contstant.

//Edit added code

```
var result = await DisplayActionSheet (Label.Alert, "Cancel", null, new string[] { "Create new", "Use Old" });
            var Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() 

            switch (result)
            {
                **case "Create new":**
                    **case Label.CreateNew**
                    {
                        //do something
                    });


                    break;

                case "Use old":
             // do somehing
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Add your code so we know what exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use SWITCH statement for something that can change value. In this case you have to relay on IF. In your case:

```
If (result == Label.CreateNew)
{
  // do something
}
else if (result == Label.Something)
{
  // do something
}
```

To understand switch better, refer to this [article](http://lazarenko.me/switch/) where the author explains how switch statement goes down to machine code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to leverage the recent additions to the switch syntax in C# 7 :

```
switch (result)
{
    case TypeOfLabel label when label == Label.CreateNew :
// ...
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause) for more details.